# Storing a value and reuse in another function cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, request, response, cypress

I am trying to write a custom command for my app where I create a real user and use its ID in a set of tests.

Since I do test on real BE and DB and I do not stub or mock any data I need to store some values.

The use case is:

1. I send a request
2. I get a response with a unique ID
3. I use this ID in another request and so on...

   ```js
    cy.request('POST', Cypress.env('active') + 'api/players', {})
    .then((response) => {
      expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
      playerID = response.body.id //<-- i need to store is value and use it below
    });

    cy.request('POST', Cypress.env('active') + 'api/kyc/processes', {
      "level": "player",
      "player": playerID, //<-- I need to use it here
      "venue": 1
    });
   ```

I have tried aliases and they do not work for this.
Also, I have tried to define variables outside of the test but it is undefined in another request.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the two `cy.request()` fire off simultaneously.

Using an additional `.then()` on the first (nesting the second) ensures sequential execution.

```js
cy.request('POST', Cypress.env('active') + 'api/players', {})
.then((response) => {
  expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
  playerId = response.body.id 
  return playerId
})
.then(playerId => {
  cy.request('POST', Cypress.env('active') + 'api/kyc/processes', {
    "level": "player",
    "player": playerId, 
    "venue": 1
  });
});
```

Comment: This answer solved it partially.
I do a registration custom command and it will be more than two steps.
So it would be then.then.then and so on.
Ho do I preserve the value from lets say first response and reuse the value in fifth request(then)?

Comment: "Preserving values" is the wrong term - requests must be made to run sequentially and using `.then()` is the simplest way. Another way is to use a reducer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to resort to writeFile and readFile.
It is really dumb but it works.
I dont like it though. I think it should be possible to pass data easier trough few requests.

Comment: This way will probably be flakey, a race condition between writing to the disk and receiving the API request.

Comment: Also this is no difference to using aliases (as long as all requests are in the same test) provided you properly `cy.wait('@myalias')`.